# Populating environment variables with secret values in AzureML

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I'm setting up an AzureML pipeline which runs a command-line application using [`CommandStep`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-pipeline-steps/azureml.pipeline.steps.commandstep?view=azure-ml-py). The command-line application expects to receive some credentials in the form of environment variables.

At the moment the best solution I can find is to wrap the command-line application in a `PythonScriptStep`, where the Python script will:

1. Retrieve the credentials from the AzureML Keyvault as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.keyvault.keyvault?view=azure-ml-py);
2. Set the environment variables; then
3. Use a subprocess call to run the command-line application.

Is there a simpler way to do this without requiring a Python script? For example, is it possible to configure the AzureML environment to populate environment variables directly from the Keyvault?

Answer (score 0):

To populate environment variables directly from the Keyvault we need to create two things in this procedure.

1. Create key vault
2. Create App in App Services

Follow the procedure to populate environment variables directly from Keyvault?

Go to **Key Vault**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now got to **App service**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Go to **Identity tab**

[image]

[image]

Select the **ON** status and click on **SAVE**

Now go to **key vault** and -> Goto **Access Policies** and click on **create**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now the app services are assigned with key vaults, now we can use the app service to get the environment variables from key vault without any programmatical manner.
Including the above steps, we need to decide what are the variables we need to get.
Copy the Vault URI: https://learning-key-vault-1234.vault.azure.net/variables/secretkey

Now the app services are assigned with key vaults, now we can use the app service to get the environment variables from key vault without any programmatical manner.

Including the above steps, we need to decide what are the variables we need to get.

Copy the Vault **URI**: `https://learning-key-vault-1234.vault.azure.net/variables/secretkey`

[image]

[image]

This will retrieve the **environmental variables** required from secret **key vault**.

Comment: I understand this method will allow me to use the secret in an App Service.  I would like to use the secret in AzureML - is there an equivalent procedure that would work there?

Comment: Let me check if any alternative solution exists.

Comment: The secret in Azure ML using the portal is the same procedure. If we need to use the coding part, then use the only the secret values then use those in coding for using in Azure ML.